# .Vue component not refreshing on each new message in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I followed the following tutorial to create a chat application. 
https://github.com/ammezie/laravel-chat

Every thing is right, messages are storing in db , showing on console in pusher desktop, all message show on page re load.

Problem is when i send a new message it not show in other user tab until i reload the page. I need to make it dynamic 
following is the code for app.js where fetch function is written

```
created() {
        this.fetchMessages();

        Echo.private('chat')
            .listen('MessageSent', (e) => {
                this.messages.push({
                    message: e.message.message,
                    user: e.user
                });
            });
    },

    methods: {
        fetchMessages() {
            axios.get('/messages').then(response => {
                this.messages = response.data;
            });
        },
        addMessage(message) {
            this.messages.push(message);

            axios.post('/messages', message).then(response => {});
        }
```

here

Following is chat view code of component

```
<template>
    <ul class="chat">
        <li class="left clearfix" v-for="message in messages">
            <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                <div class="header">
                    <strong class="primary-font">
                        {{ message.user.name }}
                    </strong>
                </div>
                <p>
                    {{ message.message }}
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['messages']
};
</script>
```

Thanks for help if some thing unclear i'll provide

Answer (score 0):

You can try.

```
methods: {

       var vm = this;
        fetchMessages() {
            axios.get('/messages').then(response => {
                vm.messages = response.data;
            });
        },
        addMessage(message) {
             var vm = this;
            vm.messages.push(message);

            axios.post('/messages', message).then(response => {});
        }
```

using this inside function causing a problem, because it refers to that particular function create a global variable with reference to `this`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry Sir! but it still having the same issue

Comment: @BabarMalik have a look mate I have updated the answer

Comment: I have to show the new received message to user without page reload, but my module shows new incomig message on page refresh.

Comment: I have tried the new code but issue remain same Sir.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check if there are Laravel Echo credentials for pusher correct in bootstrap.js